# toolbar not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement Android toolbar. Right now when I open my app it looks like this:

[image]

The tabs in the above are not from the toolbar. Its an older version of tabs from android...I am in the process of updating....

So far, the action bar did not show up which is correct, but the toolbar also did not show up. Here is my code:

MainDrawer2:

```
public class MainDrawer2 extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final String EXTRA_NAV_ITEM    = "extraNavItem";
    private static final String STATE_CURRENT_NAV = "stateCurrentNav";

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;


    private NavDrawerListAdapter mDrawerAdapter;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    private MainNavItem mCurrentNavItem;


    public static Intent createLaunchFragmentIntent(Context context, MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        return new Intent(context, MainDrawer2.class)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM, navItem.ordinal());
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        //Crashlytics.start(this);



        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //enableHomeButtonIfRequired();

        mDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                displayNavFragment((MainNavItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM)){
            MainNavItem navItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM,
                    MainNavItem.STATISTICS.ordinal())];
            displayNavFragment(navItem);
        }
        else if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentNavItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV)];
            setCurrentNavItem(mCurrentNavItem);
        }
        else{
            displayNavFragment(MainNavItem.STATISTICS);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void enableHomeButtonIfRequired()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title)
    {
        mTitle = title;
        //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        if (mCurrentNavItem == null){


        }
        else{
            outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV, mCurrentNavItem.ordinal());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    */



    private void displayNavFragment(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        //if(navItem == mCurrentNavItem){
        //  return;
        //}
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                navItem.getFragClass().getName());
        if(fragment != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment)
                    .commit();
            //setCurrentNavItem(navItem);
        }
    }

    private void setCurrentNavItem(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        int position = navItem.ordinal();
        // If navItem is in DrawerAdapter
        if(position >= 0 && position < mDrawerAdapter.getCount()){
            //mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        else{
            // navItem not in DrawerAdapter, de-select current item
            if(mCurrentNavItem != null){
                //mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mCurrentNavItem.ordinal(), false);
            }
        }

        //test to keep item not selected
        int toClear=mDrawerList.getCheckedItemPosition();

        if (toClear >= 0) {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(toClear, false);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        //setTitle(navItem.getTitleResId());
        mCurrentNavItem = navItem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }




    public void goToSearch(MenuItem item){

        //go to search page
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new Search();

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }

    public void scanBarcode(MenuItem item){

        //open scanner
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();



    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        //retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result

            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();

            //todo: set scan content into setting, load new fragment which calls async task below. New
            //todo: fragment will have same ui as search. :-)
            Fragment Fragment_one;




            FragmentManager man= this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
            BarcodeFrag fragmentNew = new BarcodeFrag();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("scanContent", scanContent);
            fragmentNew.setArguments(bundle);


            tran.replace(R.id.main, fragmentNew);//tran.
            tran.addToBackStack(null);
            //tran.commit();
            tran.commitAllowingStateLoss();


        }

        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }



}
```

My fragment_mail.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#2196F3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:choiceMode="none"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am also getting this error in android studio which may be related:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main, fragment)
                .commit();
```

You are replacing everything in `@id/main` with the fragment - including your Toolbar. Instead, your layout should have a separate FrameLayout below the Toolbar which you put your Fragments in:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#2196F3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:choiceMode="none"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Having some issues with my icons showing up for like search etc. But I will fool around with it first.

Answer (score 0):

Create a toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_my_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Now include this toolbar in your layout file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

        // Write your other code here
          ....
     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally in MainDrawer2.java

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);   
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

just move your toolbar view outside from the fragments framelayout. Perhaps your toolbar is hovered with fragment container and you didn't see it. Something small that is saw in your code is that you use method

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

when you use toolbar you should forgot for getActionBar() , but you should use getSupportActionBar().